# Three.js fragment shader: texture renders completely transparent

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

Here is my fragment shader code

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vUv;
void main()
{
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vUv);
        // gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vUv.xy); // also tried this
}
```

Here is code for uniforms:

```
 uniforms = {
            "uTime": { type: "f", value: 0.0 },
            texture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("lol.png") },
 }
```

Here is texture I load:

[image: Texture I load]

And as result - it's completely transparent. If I render any other stuff (color, circle etc.) it works.

Comment: Maybe that [forum thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/globe-of-points/2204?u=prisoner849) will be helpful.

Comment: Are you entirely sure the texture loaded? can you do 

`gl_FragColor = 1. - texture2D(texture,vUv);` and see if you get all white?

Comment: texture was loaded and everything was fine. Instead of using vUv i used gl_PointCoord

Comment: yeah, maybe you should add that to the question (and answer), without it this makes no sense. Using `gl_PointSize` yeah, vUv will be a uniform value across the point.